# Calendar-Events on Symbian OS (format etc)

Tags: calendar, symbian, synchronization

which format has a event in a symbian calendar? 
i want to write a program which syncs google calendar with symbian calendar on my smartphone, because there's no good solution for that!

edit: can i access symbian calendar on a smartphone via symbian-API?

Comment: You can use activesync to do that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you can. Check out CCalSession and CCalEntryView classes. Search Forum Nokia Wiki for samples or google these classes